# How to get current wallpaper, change it, then restore it later

Tags: java, android, android-wallpaper

I'm struggling with why this code won't compile, I'm trying to get the current wallpaper, then change it, then give the option to change it back.

Below is my code, it doesn't compile because it can't resolve symbol 'context' and it says my drawable cannot be converted to an integer which doesn't make any sense whatsoever.

I'm trying to change the drawable to a bitmap AND I have imported the import

> android.content.Context

so what is it I am doing wrong here?? this is my code, the onClick stores the wallpaper and starts the change activity, the onPush method resets the wallpaper and exits the app, any help would be appreciated thanks!

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.WallpaperInfo;
import android.app.WallpaperManager;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import java.io.IOException;
import static android.app.WallpaperManager.*;

public class SetWallpaperActivity extends Activity {

public Drawable originalWallpaper;
public Bitmap paper1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
        public void onClick(View view) {

            WallpaperManager wm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
            originalWallpaper = wm.getDrawable();

            paper1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                    originalWallpaper);
            Intent intent = new Intent(
                    ACTION_CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER);
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_LIVE_WALLPAPER_COMPONENT,
                    new ComponentName(this, MyWallpaperService.class));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    public void onPush(View view) {
    WallpaperManager wm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
    WallpaperInfo wallpaperInfo = wm.getWallpaperInfo();
    if (wallpaperInfo != null) {
        try {
            wm.setBitmap(paper1);
            finish();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    finish();
    System.exit(0);
}
}
```

This is the error code I'm getting:
'decodeResource(android.content.res.Resources, int)' in 'android.graphics.BitmapFactory' cannot be applied to '(android.content.res.Resources, android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)'

Comment: 1. change context to 'this' or remove it since the code is in activity itself and you can directly call getResources() without any context in activity.
P.S - ask specific question what error are you getting and provide some understandable code

Comment: thanks Gaurav Chauhan, I tried changing the context to this, which solved the context issue but it is still not compiling, saying that it's looking for an integer from the drawable variable originalWallpaper and not a drawable         paper1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                    originalWallpaper);

Comment: use this `Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)originalWallpaper).getBitmap();` to change drawable to bitmap

Comment: Thank you very much that worked perfectly! @Gaurav Chauhan